# how to disable a plugin

Tags: firebase, ionic3

In my new ionic project and added firebase plugin for push notification and then i added the platform and run on a device. I am getting conflict in the version of plugin

Could someone suggest me some solution

This was the error shown by my terminal window

- What went wrong:

The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.1,17.2.1]], but resolves to 17.2.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `firebase config` plugin do the following:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase-config
npm uninstall @ionic-native/firebase-config
```

Comment: I need firebase in my app

Comment: What plugins did u add

Comment: i just added firebase plugin for push notification from firebase